# Illustrator: Getting stroked colorCodes from 'javascript' opened PDFs

Tags: javascript, adobe, adobe-illustrator

a very specific question in a very specific context :D Trying to do some AdobeIllustrator scripting (language seems like js to me, but not really), but I am having a very interesting behaviour within my script. I try to set colors of specified lines (specification by grepping the color values) to pure black value (so no RGB but the 'K' value to 100) in a lot of PDFs. The interesting part is: as I open the file manually in Illustrator, my script works perfectly fine (without the opening part that is). But if I open the PDF also via said script, the values I check for are all undefined. I already tried to add a wait in case the file is not yet loaded completely and therefore I get no values, but nothing (some may already see here, I have no idea, what I do here :D ). It still remains undefined. If I run the script with already open files (aka let the script run twice without the .close), and 'reopen' them the script also works fine. Just the combination of opening and immediate changing is not working. Here is the code so far:

```
#target Illustrator

(function init() {
var dir = Folder.selectDialog("Where?");    // Here I am asking for the folder to parse through; continue in line 66 for the error
var files = dir.getFiles("*.pdf");

for(var f = 0; f < files.length; f++){
    var doc = app.open(files[f]);       //opening the pdf
    unlockDelete ();                //doing changes
    removeSwatches ();              // -''-
    convertBlacks();                // -''-
    doc.close(SaveOptions.SAVECHANGES);     // closing out and saving the current pdf
}
})();

// Unloack All Layers and Delete Hidden Layers
function unlockDelete () {
var myDoc=app.activeDocument;
var layerCount=myDoc.layers.length;

for (var ii = layerCount - 1; ii >= 0; ii--) {
    var currentLayer = myDoc.layers[ii];
    currentLayer.locked = false;
    if (currentLayer.visible == false){
        currentLayer.visible = true;
        currentLayer.remove();
        }
    }
}

// Remove All Swatches except for Pantone 485C and 185C
function removeSwatches () {
var myDoc=app.activeDocument;
var sw = myDoc.swatches;
var slen = sw.length;

for (var ii = slen - 1; ii >= 0; ii--) {
    var currentSw = sw[ii];
    if (currentSw.name == "PANTONE 185 C" || currentSw.name == "PANTONE 485 C"){
        } else {
            currentSw.remove();
        }
    }
    }

// Convert CMYK Blacks to just K Blacks
function convertBlacks() {

  var myDoc = app.activeDocument;

  with (myDoc) {

    // Convert if document isn't CMYK
    if(documentColorSpace !== DocumentColorSpace.CMYK) {
      app.executeMenuCommand('doc-color-cmyk');
    }

    // Create flat black Color
    flatBlack = new CMYKColor();
    flatBlack.black = 100;

    // Iterate through all path items
    for (var i = 0; i < myDoc.pathItems.length; i++) {
    item = myDoc.pathItems[i];
      with (item) {
    alert(stroked + " " + strokeColor.cyan + " " + strokeColor.magenta + " " + strokeColor.yellow + " " + strokeColor.black );
    // here I made some alerts to see what's wrong; interesting enough: if I come from a just opened file, the item.strokeColor.cyan is undefined as well as all the other values, except the .stroked flag
    if (item.stroked == true && item.strokeColor.cyan > 37 && item.strokeColor.cyan < 39 && item.strokeColor.magenta > 29 && item.strokeColor.magenta < 31 && item.strokeColor.yellow > 29 && item.strokeColor.yellow < 31 && item.strokeColor.black > 16 && item.strokeColor.black < 18){
        strokeColor = flatBlack;
        }
    if (stroked == true && strokeColor.cyan > 60 && strokeColor.cyan < 62 && strokeColor.magenta > 50 && strokeColor.magenta < 52 && strokeColor.yellow > 48 && strokeColor.yellow < 50 && strokeColor.black > 61 && strokeColor.black < 63){
        strokeColor = flatBlack;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Any suggestions on how to fix that are highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

My theory is the problem lies in your `convertBlacks()` function, where inside the `with (myDoc)` block you have a nested `with (item)` block.

I recommend that you make all references explicit and remove the `with` blocks.

If that doesn't fix it, please strip down your code to a minimal reproducible example. That is, just opening/closing files and checking one simple value.